Wordpress symlinks works but not as I was expected
I moved my working wordpress website from server A to server B. On new web server I open home page without any problems, but when I try to open other pages - posts (subpages) I get message

The requested URL was not found on this server.

If I set Permalink structure to Plain I can open subpages without problems, but I would like to see %postname% in my url.
OK, I played with settings in mypage.com.conf and I can achieve that my permalinks works if I set custom structure to
/index.php/%postname%/ .
My subpages works and I see in url
https://www.mypage.com/index.php/postname/

This is my mypage.com.conf settings:
<Directory "/var/www/html/mypage">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
</Directory>

What should I do to get working permalinks that URL will be https://www.mypage.com/postaname/
I try different settings in my .conf files. I expect some good advice to find solution

Solution!
I find that if I add in mypage.com.conf
AllowOverride All

Everything works as expected ;-)
